# web.py doesnt detect GET method

Tags: python, web.py

I am a noob to both python and web.py worlds.

I just created three files

**urls.py**

```
url_mappings = (
    '/', 'index'
)
```

**index.py**

```
class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "<h1>Hello World</h1>"

    def POST (self):
        return "<h1>Hello World in POST</h1>"
```

**webstart.py**

```
import web
import index
from urls import url_mappings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application (url_mappings, globals())
    app.run()
```

I start my dev server with python webstart.py and when I hit localhost:8080, it sends None to the browser and in the logs I see the following

127.0.0.1:52822 - - [19/Mar/2013 20:44:18] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 405 Method Not Allowed
127.0.0.1:52822 - - [19/Mar/2013 20:44:18] "HTTP/1.1 GET /favicon.ico" - 404 Not Found

What am I missing?

Comment: Isn't stuff this basic covered in the 'users guide' to web.py?

Comment: In the users guide (http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial#starting), they have all the code in a single file and I tried that, it works. But when I keep all of them in three different files, it wont work :(

Comment: Todays important lesson - only change one thing at a time - In that vein, is the order an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web.py cannot find controller class, you should either change urls.py:

```
url_mappings = (
    '/', 'index.index'
)
```

or import `index` class in webstart.py

```
from index import index
```

i.e. you should either map url directly to `module_name.class_name` or `import class_name from module_name` so `class_name` is available in global scope.